# MS Report Builder how to show last 5 rows

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0

I want to be able to show the last 5 rows from a table in MS report builder 3.0.
I am trying to show the highest top 5 "amounts" in the table below but in ascending order.
ie. I want the display name 6-10 from the table below. 
Is this possible?

```
name        amount 
-------------------
name 1      10
name 2      22
name 3      23
...
name 6      60
name 7      71
name 8      72
name 9      80
name 10     100
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could do this is a simple SQL statement with TOP 5, and use that as your dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Tablix Filters to get the bottom 5 rows of your dataset ordered by `Amount`.

Go to tablix properties window, under `Filters` tab use settings like these:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can hide the rows bases field's value.

For example: Use Row Visibility and try below expression for first 5 rows.

```
=IIF(Fields!Value1.Value="something you want to check",True,False)
```

*I would also suggest to do some changes in SQL Query.*